# Is it okay to use same handler for different redux actions?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I use redux - toolkit in my app with createAsyncThunk.
I have some "cart" reducer and inside it I have "CART_CLEARED" action.
"CART_CLEARED" is being called when user press on "Clear Cart" button.
But now, I also have to clear cart when user made order.
So, when user made order, I dispatch "createOrder" thunk (created with createAsyncThunk) and then, in same "cart" reducer, listen for "createOrder.fulfilled" action and I have to do the same thing - clear my cart products.

```
const initialState = {
  products: {};
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...some reducers,
    
    CART_CLEARED: (state) => {
      state.products = initialState.products
    },
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createOrder.fulfilled, (state) => {
      state.products = initialState.products
    });
  },
});
```

Is it normal practice to move this handler into a separate function? or is there some other solution possible within redux?

```
const initialState = {
  products: {};
}

const CART_CLEARED_HANDLER = (state) => {
  state.products = initialState.products
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...some reducers,

    CART_CLEARED: (state) => CART_CLEARED_HANDLER(state)
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createOrder.fulfilled, (state) => CART_CLEARED_HANDLER(state));
  },
});
```

Comment: IMO, if you're going to change more than one state variable (in CART_CLEARED handler), reusing a separate function makes better sense (reduces maintenance cost, causes less bug, etc), if it will stay as simple as in your example, then it's ok to use it like this.

Comment: I think `createOrder` action belongs to `orders` slice. In my opinion, clearing cart in `createOrder` thunk is not a good approach. Instead, you need to dispatch `CART_CLEARED` action after order is created in your component.

Answer (score 1):

I don't why you wouldn't want to make your code more DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself).

I'd reduce this a bit more by removing the anonymous function too, just assign the reducer function to the case.

```
const initialState = {
  products: {};
}

const clearCartHandler = (state) => {
  state = initialState;
}

export const cartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "cart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    ...some reducers,
    CART_CLEARED: clearCartHandler
  },
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(createOrder.fulfilled, clearCartHandler);
  },
});
```